# Location Permissions being requested again onRequestPermissionsResult

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, android-location

I am trying to build a simple example regarding the permissions request process in Android N.

I have declared the usage of the `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` usage inside my manifest file. And I am trying to handle the request inside its own method:

```
public boolean permissionsChecker() {
        // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            } else {

                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                        MY_REQUEST_PERMISSION_COARSE_LOCATION);
                return true;

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
        }
        return false;

    }
```

This gets asked first when the app connects:

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if(permissionsChecker()){
                mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            }
        }
        if(mLastLocation != null){
            Log.i(TAG, mLastLocation.getLatitude() + "");
            Log.i(TAG, mLastLocation.getLongitude() + "");
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Still awaiting permissions, something went wrong");
        }

    }
```

My problem is that it was still returning null for the `mLastLocation` instance and I was able to see it in the debugger, according to the docs I have to set everything up once there is a request code inside the `onRequestPermissionsResult()` callback, but when I try to set the mLastLocation instance inside of it I get the red line telling me that I need to make a permission request:

```
 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case MY_REQUEST_PERMISSION_COARSE_LOCATION: {
                if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    // permissiosn was granted yaaaay! Do the coarse location related task you need to do
                    //Log.i(TAG, mLastLocation.getLongitude() + "");
                    //Log.i(TAG, mLastLocation.getLatitude() + "");
                    //mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                } else {
                    // permissions denied, boo! Disable the functionality that depends on this permissions
                }
                return;

                // Still inside the case checker, perform other permissions that this app might require working on
            } // end of case test for the acces coarse location
        } // end of stich statmeent
    } // end of onRequestPermissionsResult()
```

What is the purpose of asking for permissions if the callback is going to make me ask for it again? what am I doing wrong? I am not getting much from the docs(lack of experience I know) and would like to know how to fix this. Any pointers and code suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "I get the red line telling me that I need to make a permission request" -- you get the red undersquiggle indicating that the IDE cannot determine if you are only executing this code when you have the runtime permission. The IDE is not an all-powerful omniscient deity, which is good, because a buggy deity could be *very* problematic. "would like to know how to fix this" -- ignore it temporarily. Run your code. Once your code is working in this area, use the quick-fix to add the `@SuppressLint` annotation to get rid of the red undersquiggle.

Comment: where are you calling `mGoogleApiClient.connect();`..post full code..

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 that one is being done inside the onStart() method

Answer (score 1):

The `permissionChecker()` usage looks like it is throwing things off. Just because you have requested the permission does not mean it has been granted.

This Droicon talk will help explain the permissions model and usage: https://youtu.be/WGz-alwVh8A

You may also find this library helpful for keeping your code simpler and easier to follow: https://github.com/hiqes/andele

Comment: Wouldn't the user clicking on the 'allow' button mean that the permission has been granted?

Comment: Yes, but your app will not know that has happened until `onRequestPermissionResult()` is called to inform you that it was granted.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. As for what I understand from the docs, when you need to request a particular permission you do it(such as the permissionsChecker()) the permissionsChecker then shows the dialog, the user accepts it, this then passes the result to the callback and after that and if the permission was given by the user it lets you do whatever you want to. My point is that at that point it still won't let me instantiate the location and I do not know why. Thanks for the link to the github repo! It looks useful and I will look into it as soon as possible.

Comment: Yes, though the way your code is structured it assumes that when `requestPermissions()` is called that execution stops immediately then continues once the user response is acquired. This is not the case. `requestPermissions()` is an asynchronous call, like sending an `Intent`. So your code will complete execution in the current connect (`onConnected`) then get called back later at `onRequestPermissionsResult()` where you can determine whether or not you are allowed to make protected calls.